# Empty moongose result in nested query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Ok, here is my code:

```
router.get('/',middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  var clave = req.query.id;
  Students.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err,foundStudent){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      var estudiante=foundStudent.matriculaT0;
      var modelo=foundStudent.modelo;
      Horarios.find({matricula:estudiante,claveMateria:clave}).exec(function(err,foundHorario){
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
        }else{
          var grupo=foundHorario[0].CRN;
          Grades.find({CRN:grupo}).exec(function(err,foundGrade){
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
            }else{
              var pagina="grade/"+modelo+"/"+clave;  
            res.render(pagina,{horario:foundHorario, student:foundStudent, grade:foundGrade});
}})}})}})});
```

Basically I'm working with three diferent models, the students, the schedule and the grades. So to access the grades of each subject per students first I look for the selected student and take his school id number (matricula) and the model it belongs too (there are two).

Once I have that I look in the school schedule for the student subjects using the "matricula" and "clave" (the subject key code" I got from the request. Once I get the 7 subjects from the students I look for a specic subject code (CRN) so I can load it's grades in a ejs template (every subject has a different grading system...)

So, everything works great, the rendering of the page and looking for the students and the schedule, the only problem is the last query, foundGrade comes back as empty but when I do the same query in the mongo console I get the correct result.

```
 var grupo=foundHorario[0].CRN
```

Gives back the correct result, a subject key in the form of a string and in the grade model the subject key (CRN) is also a string. I have also made sure that the collection name is in plural so that's not the problem either, any ideas?

Comment: Great cb hell }); }})}})}})});

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT THE ANSWER, but I think you can continue *explaining/solving* your trouble from here!

```
router.get('/',middleware.isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  try{
       let clave  = req.query.id;

       let foundStudent = await Students.findById(req.params.id);

       let estudiante = foundStudent.matriculaT0;

       let modelo  = foundStudent.modelo;

       let foundHorario = await Horarios.find({
            matricula   :estudiante,
            claveMateria:clave
        });

       let grupo  = foundHorario[0].CRN;

       let foundGrade = await Grades.find({CRN:grupo});

       let pagina="grade/"+modelo+"/"+clave;  

       return res.render(pagina,{
                  horario : foundHorario,
                  student : foundStudent, 
                  grade   : foundGrade
        });

  }catch(err){

       return res.status(400).json(err);

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Im fairly new to node and I had never used async functions before so I really appreciated.

Comment: Yesss you have used async functions all time but not the async/await paradigm!